# Redirect all pages containing a particular part to home using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Recently my site got hacked, and tons of pages were generated. Most of them end with strings like `?_t=77`, `?_t=97`, and `?_t=56` etc. Basically, the `?_t=` part is common in all of them.

How do I create a .htaccess rule to redirect all the links with `?_t=` to home?

Some redirects I've already created:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /profile/1320172681 /u/DanLiu
Redirect 301 /profile/387899125 /u/LuckyMaheshwari
Redirect 301 /profile/15379797 /u/manishchopra
Redirect 301 /profile/335596945 /u/MatthewNord
Redirect 301 /profile/94097446 /u/abhimanyu
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for your comment. I have not tried any. I don't know htaccess codes

Comment: Does your site already have a .htaccess file from your CMS or similar? Post it.

Comment: Sorry but on Stack Overflow its highly encouraged to show your efforts(there is nothing right or wrong in tried code), so please edit your code. Once you edit it I could add my answer then.

Comment: One thing that is very important - if your site got hacked and stuff content generated, you have to assume that the site code is compromised and the attacker retains control of it in one way or another. It's entirely possible that the hack can overwrite your site's htaccess to keep itself alive. Usually it is necessary to wipe it and restore from the last backup before the attack, then apply any patches necessary to make sure it doesn't get hacked again straight away.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes it does have htaccess. I've updated the post. Also, the site is clean now. It was because of a cheap web host. I've moved to Cloudways and cleaned the site entirely.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I've updated the post

Comment: @heyitsritesh, thanks for doing so, I have added an answer now, you could test it and we could discuss about it, in answer's comments section, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown attempts/samples, please try following htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
##making your Rewrite engine ON here.
RewriteEngine On
##Rewriting urls with ending with ?_t=digits to home page here.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_t=\d+/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L,QSD]
##Rewriting home page url to index.php here.
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [QSA,L]
###put your rest of htaccess Rules from here onwards.

Redirect 301 /profile/1320172681 /u/DanLiu
Redirect 301 /profile/387899125 /u/LuckyMaheshwari
Redirect 301 /profile/15379797 /u/manishchopra
Redirect 301 /profile/335596945 /u/MatthewNord
Redirect 301 /profile/94097446 /u/abhimanyu
</IfModule>
```

Comment: FYI: As mentioned in comments section of my shown code, this is considering that your home page is being served by index.php in backend. If its not then make sure you place your Rules by which your home page is getting served under my posted rules.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this rule: `RewriteRule \?_t=\d+/?$ / [R=301,NC,L]` but it didn't work. I even placed it at the beginning as you did but no luck.

Comment: @heyitsritesh, ok please do let me know what is the sample URL you are hitting here? And what is error you are getting?

Comment: You can't match a query string in RewriteRule. It has to be matched in `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _t=` followed by a RewriteRule

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It looks like this `example.com/43146758?_t=77`

Error says `The page you requested could not be found.`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Sorry my bad, let me fix it now, thanks for letting know here.

Comment: @heyitsritesh, Thanks to Michael Berkowski, I have tried to fix the code now, please do try my updated Rules once. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it redirected, but incorrectly. It redirected from `example.com/43146758?_t=77` to `example.com/?_t=77`

Comment: @heyitsritesh, sure, that is fixed now. Kindly do check my updated rules once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, it worked perfectly this time! Thank you so much :) I really appreciate your help, support, and time.

Comment: Thanks to @MichaelBerkowski as well for the assistance :)

Comment: @heyitsritesh, Your welcome. cheers and happy learning :)